# How can I nest my foreign object in my projection?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, slick

I have two tables with a dependency of the following:

Table Movies
id , name, genre, directorId

Table Directors
id, first_name, last_name

I'd like to be able to query my movies and have the projection include the nested directors model.

rather than ex:
(1, "Good Will Hunting", 1)

I'd prefer
(1, "Good Will Hunting", "Matt", "Damon")

Preferably, I'd like to serialize this to JSON and it can be nested in the top level movies or nested in the 'director' field.

Answer (score 0):

If you use tuples:

```
for( m <- Movies; d <- Directors ) yield (m.id,m.name,d)
```

gives you `(1, "Good Will Hunting", (1, "Matt", "Damon"))`

Using HLists:

```
for( m <- Movies; d <- Directors ) yield m.id :: m.name :: d
```

gives you `1 :: "Good Will Hunting" :: 1 :: Matt :: Damon :: Nil` .

Comment: I find myself constantly having to expand the result type (increase the tuple) of my find method in my DAO to include every new foreign key join type. Is this the expected way?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Please provide some code. Maybe better as a separate question.